# Reading and writing a std::vector<int> to / from registry with WriteProfileBinary

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, registry, stdvector, binary-data

I am getting myself into a pickle here!

I have a simple `<std::vector<int>` container and what I want to do is read / write it to a binary registry key. I started with:

```
    std::vector<int> vSortedColumnIndexInfo = dlgColumns.SortedEditorColumnIndexInfo();
    theApp.WriteProfileBinary(_T("Options"), _T("EditorSortedColumnIndexInfo"), 
        vSortedColumnIndexInfo.data, 
        vSortedColumnIndexInfo.size);
```

But this will not compile:

> error C3867:
> `std::vector<int,std::allocator<int>>::data`: non-standard syntax; use
> `&` to create a pointer to member
>
> error C3867:
> `std::vector<int,std::allocator<int>>::size`: non-standard syntax; use
> `&` to create a pointer to member

Why is it saying this? What is the correct way to read / write a `std::vector<int>` to / from a binary registry key? It can be changed from an `int` if required.

---

#### Update 1

Based on the comments I now have:

```
std::vector<int> vSortedColumnIndexInfo = dlgColumns.SortedEditorColumnIndexInfo();
theApp.WriteProfileBinary(_T("Options"), _T("EditorSortedColumnIndexInfo"), 
    reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(vSortedColumnIndexInfo.data()),
    gsl::narrow<UINT>(vSortedColumnIndexInfo.size() * sizeof(int)));
```

Comment: The `.data()` and `.size()` members are **functions** returning values. You forgot to add the `()` to make the function calls.

Comment: @AdrianMole Doh! Not it complains: error C2664: `BOOL CWinApp::WriteProfileBinary(LPCTSTR,LPCTSTR,LPBYTE,UINT)`: cannot convert argument 3 from `_Ty *` to `LPBYTE`.

Comment: You'll need to cast the `data()` value to a `BYTE*` ... and multiply the `size()` value by `sizeof(int)`. Reading the data back fom the registry will also present you with some potentially nasty pitfalls ... but it is possible.

Comment: @AdrianMole OK, I think I now have the "writing" OK and need to work on the "reading". Since you referred to `sizeof(int)` I am now concerned about when users run 64 bit v 32 bit of my installed app. `int` might not be a good way to go here.

Comment: The **value** of `sizeof(int)` doesn't change between 32- and 64-bit Windows. But note that the `.size()` member returns a `size_t`, which *does* change.

Comment: I tried to glean stuff from this answer to another of my questions but things are different as I an working with integer vectors and not byte vectors: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69719862/how-do-i-save-the-result-from-getprofilebinary-into-a-smart-pointer

Comment: @AdrianMole Please see my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I know my values will be under 256 I have decided to stick with `BYTE` for the container.

#### Writing to Registry

```
std::vector<BYTE> vExcludedColumns;

// POpulate vector

UINT uSize = gsl::narrow<UINT>(sizeof(BYTE) * vExcludedColumns.size());
theApp.WriteProfileBinary(
    strSection, 
    _T("AssignStatesEx"),
    vExcludedColumns.data(),
    uSize
);
theApp.WriteProfileInt(strSection, _T("AssignStatesExSize"), uSize);
```

#### Reading from Registry

```
std::vector<BYTE> vExcludedColumns;
UINT uSize = theApp.GetProfileInt(strSection, _T("AssignStatesExSize"), 0);
UINT uSizeRead = 0;
BYTE* temp = nullptr;
theApp.GetProfileBinary(strSection, _T("AssignStatesEx"), &temp, &uSizeRead);
if (uSizeRead == uSize)
{
    vExcludedColumns.resize(uSizeRead, 0);
    memcpy(vExcludedColumns.data(), temp, uSizeRead);
}
delete[] temp;
temp = nullptr;
```

---

I believe that this will still work for both 32 bit and 64 bit.

I am open to comments if this code can be improved or simplified.

---

#### Updated

Here is the same code, but added into public app methods:

```
std::vector<BYTE> CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp::GetProfileVector(CString strSection, CString strKey)
{
    std::vector<BYTE> vData;
    UINT uSize = theApp.GetProfileInt(strSection, strKey + _T("Size"), 0);
    UINT uSizeRead = 0;
    BYTE* temp = nullptr;
    theApp.GetProfileBinary(strSection, strKey, &temp, &uSizeRead);
    if (uSizeRead == uSize)
    {
        vData.resize(uSizeRead, 0);
        memcpy(vData.data(), temp, uSizeRead);
    }
    delete[] temp;
    temp = nullptr;
    return vData;
}


void CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp::WriteProfileVector(CString strSection, CString strKey, std::vector<BYTE> vData)
{
    UINT uSize = gsl::narrow<UINT>(sizeof(BYTE) * vData.size());
    theApp.WriteProfileBinary(
        strSection,
        strKey,
        vData.data(),
        uSize
    );
    theApp.WriteProfileInt(strSection, strKey + _T("Size"), uSize);
}
```